# Android App: Not able to read and write data from the prepopulated SQLite db

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

In Physical mobile devices,
Hybrid app is not able to read and write data from the prepopulated SQLite databases.
Whereas runtime created databases are accessible eventhough both the files are in the same file location in mobile.

In Emulator,
The app is working fine in both preloaded DB and runtime DB with out issues.

Since our application is a HTML5, javascript app, error traces donot have much information.

Needed help to find a solution for this problem/ atleast a minimal guidance on finding solution/debugging methodology.